# Idempotently creating a user in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to use Phoenix's out of box `create/2` function to use it for my user sign up use case. For this to work, I need to create a user idempotently. I'm having trouble finding the most idomatic way to do this in Elixir.

For example, this is Phoenix's out of box snippet for creating a resource (in this case a user):

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, user} ->
    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
    |> put_resp_header("location", user_path(conn, :show, user))
    |> render("show.json", user: user)
  {:error, changeset} ->
    conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(BrewswapApi.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
end
```

What'd I'd like to do is first check if the user exists by a specific field. If it exists then return a 200 with the object or else run the code above.

Would I use nested case statement for this or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using function plugs to return existing user

That's a great case to use [function plugs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/understanding-plug#section-function-plugs). You can see in the example how they transformed the `show` action from multiple nested cases to using plugs. Note the use of [`halt/1`](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#halt/1) to prevent the request from proceeding downstream.

However I see returning the existing user instance on sign up fail as a security issue. It would be better to return an error if the "field" has already been taken.

### Using unique constraint to return error

To do so, since the "field" must be unique for users, you will need to create a `unique_index` and then define a [`unique_constraint`](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3) in your `changeset`.

Now in your `create` action, if you are trying to insert a user with a duplicate "field", the `changeset` will be invalid and the block from `{:error, changeset}` will run.

Comment: Right good point, in this case though it's a private API where the POST info represents an authenticated Facebook user.  So the unique key is on his/her Facebook ID.  Therefore when a user taps "sign up with Facebook" it also acts as a Facebook sign in call as well, that way the consumer can avoid 2x calls to the server (one to check existence, one to register).  Thanks for the tip on function plugs, I'll check this out and report back later on how it worked out.